# malformed header from script 'index.php' bad header, despite that I didn't set any header

Tags: php, heroku

I'm quite new to PHP, so if I overlook something obvious, please bear with me.

I deployed my PHP API(no framework, vanilla PHP) on Heroku.
However, when I try to login from Postman, that API just returns 500:internal server error.
So I checked the log from Heroku dashboard, and the following message was displayed;

```
 [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 154:tid 140045260420864] [client 10.1.49.183:25268] malformed header from script 'login.php': Bad header: {"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV
```

However, I haven't set any header in login.php.

```
$access_token = $codec->encode($payload);
$refresh_token_expiry = time()+432000;
$refresh_token = $codec->encode([
  'sub'=>$user['id'],
  'exp'=>$refresh_token_expiry
]);
echo json_encode([
  'access_token'=>$access_token,
  'refresh_token'=>$refresh_token
]);
```

The error above says the header which includes `$access_token` is malformed. However, as you can see, between its declaration and echo, I didn't set `$access_token` as a header.

I can't wrap my head around this. If anyone should shed some lights on it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Try `echo json_encode('hello')` and see if that appears as a header in the log as well. It looks like your body is being interpreted as a header?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried, and it indeed appeared as header in the log. `malformed header from script 'login.php': Bad header: "hello`. Have you got any idea of why it's interpreted as a header?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you. Have you created a test file that is literally `<?php echo 'test';` and see if it does same behaviour? That would point to some sort of environment configuration issue with heroku.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I literally checked every line to detect the cause, and finally found it. I removed `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *")` and tokens are no longer interpreted as headers. Thank you for your corporation!

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us.

Comment: @Chris Hey, man, that's not fair. Some readers might be hard-of-hearing.